# MariaDB server configuration for MyISAM to InnoDB migration

Tags: mariadb

Please help with MariaDB server configuration.
I see that buffer pool is only 38% of RAM and I think it has to be changed. I want to migrate all Aria and MyISAM tables to InnoDB engine. Will I have enougth RAM and MariaDB server will work correctly and without crash? If I incrase Buffer pool to 10GB will that be enough?

RAM:

```
free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           15G        15G       607M         4K       138M       7.5G
-/+ buffers/cache:       7.5G       8.2G
Swap:         1.0G       135M       888M
```

InnoDB configuration:

```
> SELECT VARIABLE_NAME, SESSION_VALUE, GLOBAL_VALUE FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_VARIABLES WHERE   VARIABLE_NAME IN ('innodb_buffer_pool_size','innodb_additional_mem_pool_size','innodb_log_buffer_size','tmp_table_size','max_connections','sort_buffer_size','read_buffer_size','join_buffer_size','binlog_cache_size');
+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| VARIABLE_NAME           | SESSION_VALUE | GLOBAL_VALUE |
+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| BINLOG_CACHE_SIZE       | NULL          | 32768        |
| MAX_CONNECTIONS         | NULL          | 300          |
| JOIN_BUFFER_SIZE        | 262144        | 262144       |
| SORT_BUFFER_SIZE        | 2097152       | 2097152      |
| READ_BUFFER_SIZE        | 131072        | 131072       |
| TMP_TABLE_SIZE          | 16777216      | 16777216     |
| INNODB_LOG_BUFFER_SIZE  | NULL          | 16777216     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE | NULL          | 6442450944   |
+-------------------------+---------------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0,16 sec)
```

Data with indexes:

```
+--------+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| ENGINE | Data GB | Index GB | Total GB | Num Tables |
+--------+---------+----------+----------+------------+
| NULL   |    NULL |     NULL |     NULL |          8 |
| Aria   |    14.3 |      3.9 |     18.3 |          7 |
| InnoDB |    67.1 |     50.6 |    117.7 |        141 |
| MyISAM |    65.2 |     21.0 |     86.3 |         16 |
+--------+---------+----------+----------+------------+
4 rows in set (0,40 sec)
```

Comment: Why do you think that doubling the buffer pool size will  benefit your workload?

Comment: Set the buffer_pool to 70% of _available_ RAM.  See also:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much of your InnoDB/ Aria / MyISAM data is actively used by MariaDB in queries? The `show global status` below will show you.

`show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool%'`, 100% usage of `Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data` actually ok, look at [innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-status-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests) vs [innodb_buffer_pool_reads](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-status-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_reads) - reads should be low (<1% of `innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests`) after a warmup and running for a while.

Under allocation of innodb buffer pool will just mean more requests go to disk. Overallocation of innodb buffer pool will result in OOM once it fills up.

[innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-buffer-pool/#innodb_buffer_pool_size) can be changed at runtime with `set global innodb_buffer_pool_size=value` (note can't use `10G` as value with G as a suffix, but you can do `10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`). So start small, increment until the read requests drop down to a small amount, and don't forget to put the final value in the configuration file so that a restart will restore to this value on startup.